# Calculating median difference of a column in BigQuery - Analytic functions cannot be arguments to aggregate functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, average, aggregate-functions, median

I have a column with all numbers called `id`. I'd like to get the median value of the difference between ids. For example, if the ids (sorted ascendingly) are [1, 5, 30, 35], then the difference would be [4, 25, 5] and the median. would be 5.

I tried

```
SELECT id - LAG(id) OVER (order by id) FROM `table` ORDER BY id ASC
```

and this produced a column of differences. However, if I try

```
SELECT AVG(id - LAG(id) OVER (order by id)) FROM `table` ORDER BY id ASC
```

or `PERCENTILE_CONT(x, 0.5)` for median, then I get an error that says Analytic functions cannot be arguments to aggregate functions. How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t mix window and aggregate functions like that. You would need to use `lag()` *in a subquery*, then aggregate in the outer query:

```
select avg(id - lag_id) avg_id_diff
from (
    select id, lag(id) over(order by id) lag_id
    from mytable 
) t
```

If you are looking for the median difference rather than the average:

```
select percentile_cont(id - lag_id, 0.5) over() mediam_id_diff
from (
    select id, lag(id) over(order by id) lag_id
    from mytable 
) t
limit 1
```

`percentile_cont` is available as a window function only (not as an aggregate function), which is why we use `over()` and `limit` clauses.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have a further question, what if I want the average but with extreme values removed? Let's say I want the average of values between 0.25 and 0.75 percentiles? Thanks.